# Ionic2: Wait for navParams.get to finish before loading page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm developing a mobile app using Ionic2. In my constructor I'm using:

```
this.result = this.navParams.get('result');
```

to receive some data from another page. My ionViewDidLoad() method looks like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() { 
  this.init();
}
```

Within the init() method I'm about to access this.result.
However, I'm experiencing, that the init() method tries to use this.result before there is any data in it. When I do an console.log(Object.keys(this.result)) within init() it shows me an empty object. A few miliseconds later, the data is there.

How can I wait for the navParams.get method to be completed before calling the init() method without just using a manual timeout?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just call navparams in ionviewload?

Comment: Could you provide which Ionic version are you using by running ionic info in your console.

Comment: I have tested ionViewDidLoad, ionViewDidEnter, ionViewWillEnter, all these can recieve the result instantly. 

So the question would be how did you get this result? Is this from an API? If so you should only open this current page after you have successfully received your result from the API or request the result right after you have opened this page. Then you won't have this problem.

Comment: I'm using Ionic 3.0.1.

Comment: Strangely, everything works as expected when I use ionViewDidEnter() instead of ionViewDidLoad(). However, I think the root of the problem is that I try to pass "this.result" to early to the page. I opened a new topic for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932438/identify-when-nested-for-loops-and-if-statement-with-one-asynchronous-function-c