# Identify when nested FOR loops and IF statement with one asynchronous function call are done

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a function with nested for-loops and IF statements and one call of an asynchronous function. The structure looks similar to this:

```
search(){
    // for loop 1
    for (let i in object){

      // IF statement 1
      if (condition1){

        // for loop 2
        for (let o in object[i]){

          // IF statement 2
          if (condition2){

            // call of an asynchronous function
            this.asyncFunction().then( data => {

              this.result.push(data)

            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to call one function (let's say `goToNextPage()` ) as soon as all loops are done and all async-function calls are completed and, thus, my `this.result` object is completed.

However, I don't know how to manage this. I tried to work with counters, to know when the last `object[i]` is handled and when the last `object[i][o]` was handled to call `goToNextPage()` afterwards. But this doesn't work properly, if the last object fails one if statement. Then `goToNextPage()` is called, while the async function of the second to last object is still running.

And I can't just call `goToNextPage()` within

```
this.asyncFunction().then( data => {
    this.result.push(data)
    // call it here, if last element is reached
});
```

since then it would not be called if the last element doesn't meet one of the IF statements.

I hope it's understandable what my problem is and that there is a solution for this...

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koleman answered this perfectly on the official Ionic forum and thereby helped me with the solution: [Link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/identify-when-nested-for-loops-and-if-statement-with-one-asynchronous-function-call-are-done/89974/4?u=jaykay)

His approach is to insert promises in the structure and to use `Promise.all(promises).then(...)` to wait until all promises are resolved.

```
search(){
   let promises = [];
    // for loop 1
    for (let i in object){
        // IF statement 1
        if (condition1){
            // for loop 2
            for (let o in object[i]){
                // IF statement 2
                if (condition2){
                    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
                        this.asyncFunction().then( data => resolve(data)); 
                    });
                    promises.push(promise); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!promises.length){
            reject('Something went worng!');
        }else{
            Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
                this.result = this.result.concat(results);
                resolve('We done it!');
            });
        }        
    });         
  }

  search().then(
    successText => {
        console.log(statusText);
        console.log(this.result);
    },
    failText => {
        console.log(failText);
    }
  );
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Fair enough. I improved the answer as suggested,